# Integrating AssertJ and ExtentReport

Tags: assertj

Here's an example method explaining what I'd like to do.

```
public void myMethod(Method m){
    report = new ExtentReports("filename");     
    test = report.startTest("testName");

   String actual = "sssssss";
   String expected = "xxxxxxxx";

    // what I can do with AssertJ id have a nice readable test
    assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected).withFailMessage("BOINK!");

    // what I can do with ExtentReports
    if (!actual.equals(expected)) test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "BOINK");

    // what I want to extend assertJ to do
    assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected).extentLog(test, LogStatus.FAIL, "BOINK");
}
```

My question would be how to extend AssertJ with another action, the  .extentLog(args) method?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to directly extend AssertJ as you suggest, it would mean modifying AssertJ core API.

One option is to wrap the assertj assertions with a lambda to catch the assertion error (if any), pass it to the extent reports to capture the error message (don't forget to rethrow the error to have a failing test).